# using socket.io with express router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I am fairly new to node.js, I am trying to build a webchat and so far I have a server.js file and a router.js file that should have all my routes inside. I am not using express-generator. I would like to use socket.io but on my current setup it doesn't work.
 Here is what I have

**server.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const layout = require('express-layout');
const app = express();
const routes = require('./router');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io=require('socket.io')(server);


app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

const middleware = [
    layout(),
    express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')),
    bodyParser.urlencoded(),


];

app.use(middleware);

app.use('/', routes);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.status(404).send("Sorry can't find that!");
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.status(500).send('Something broke!');
});

io.on('connection',function (socket) {
    console.log('yo');
});




server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`App running at http://localhost:3000`);
});
```

**router.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const {check, validationResult}=require('express-validator');
const { matchedData } = require('express-validator/filter')
const app = express();


    router.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.render('index', {
            data: {},
            errors: {}
        })
    });

    router.post('/enter', [
        check('username')
            .isLength({min: 1})
            .withMessage('Username is required')   //implement personalized check
    ], (req, res) => {
        const errors = validationResult(req);

        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return res.render('index', {
                data: req.body,
                errors: errors.mapped()
            })
        }
        const data = matchedData(req)

    });



module.exports = router;
```

It should log "yo" on the console but it doesn't. I already tried to move the socket.io setup part to router.js, it doesn't give any errors but it does not log anything. Also if I set up correctly socket.io on my server.js, how do I pass it to router.js?

**EDIT**
there is the index.ejs file that has some client code that initializes the connection with socket.io

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Global.io</title>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/index.css">
    <script>
        var socket = io();


        socket.on('connect', function () { // TIP: you can avoid listening on `connect` and listen on events directly too!
            console.log('yo client');
        });
    </script>
  <!--  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>

    <script src="/scripts/client.js" defer></script> -->

</head>
<body>
<h1>Start debating about the change</h1>
<div id="wrapper">

    <form id="formElem" method="post" action="/enter" novalidate>
        <% if (errors.username) { %>
            <div class="error"><%= errors.username.msg %></div>
        <% } %>
        <input id='name' type="text" name="user" placeholder="User name" class=" <%= errors.username ? 'form-field-invalid' : ''%>">
        <select name="room" id="room">
        </select>
        <button type="submit" id="submit-b">Submit</button>
    </form>



</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Now it gives an error saying io is undefined.

Comment: Do you have client-side socket.io code that is initiating the socket.io connection?

Comment: edited the question with client code

Comment: You don't show a script tag that loads the client-side socket.io library before you try to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You need this:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Before the script that tries to use socket.io in your web page.  That script loads the socket.io library and defines the `io` symbol so you can then use it after the library has been loaded.